# Can someone explain how the callstack in Eclipse works?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, callstack

I am trying to debug a simple Plug-in in Eclipse. I've put breakpoints everywhere, especially in the `Activator` class.

As soon as I start the plugin (by `Debug -> Application`), I get a huge callstack and I don't know how to read it or what anything means.

Could someone explain in simple terms how this callstack is generated and what each individual item might represent?

[image]

Comment: I just want a general understanding. Where do they come from? What is calling them? What do some of them mean?

Answer (score 2):

Each call to any function (including nested functions as well) will form a "stackframe" on the stack, which contains the argument(s) to the function, the return address where it goes back to on return and any local variables inside the function.